# JAXB marshall elements with comments

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

So I have a class like

```
@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Item {

@XmlAttribute
private String idA;

private String nameA;

@XmlAttribute
private String idB;

private String nameB;

@XmlAttribute
private String idC;

private String nameC;

public Item() {
}

public Item(String idA, String nameA, String idB, String nameB, String idC, String nameC) {
    this.idA = idA;
    this.nameA = nameA;
    this.idB = idB;
    this.nameB = nameB;
    this.idC = idC;
    this.nameC = nameC;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Item [nameA = " + nameA + ", nameB = " + nameB + ", nameC = " + nameC + "]";
}
}
```

And its container:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Items {

private List<Item> items;

public Items() {
}

public Items(List<Item> items) {
    this.items = items;
}
}
```

And I'm using this listener to write comments after each item:

```
public class AddCommentsListener extends Marshaller.Listener {

private XMLStreamWriter xsw;

public AddCommentsListener(XMLStreamWriter xsw) {
    this.xsw = xsw;
}

@Override
public void beforeMarshal(Object source) {
}

@Override
public void afterMarshal(Object source) {
    if (source instanceof Item) {
        try {
            xsw.writeComment(source.toString());
        } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
        }
    }

}
}
```

Finally my test class is:

```
public class Test {
public static <T> void saveToXml(T entity, OutputStream stream) {
    try {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(entity.getClass());
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setListener(new AddCommentsListener(XMLOutputFactory.newFactory().createXMLStreamWriter(stream)));
        marshaller.marshal(entity, stream);
    } catch (JAXBException | XMLStreamException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i =0 ;i < 100; i++) {
        String idA = String.format("idA %s", i);
        String nameA = String.format("locationA %s", i);
        String idB = String.format("idB %s", i);
        String nameB = String.format("locationB %s", i);
        String idC = String.format("idC %s", i);
        String nameC = String.format("locationC %s", i);
        items.add(new Item(idA, nameA, idB, nameB, idC, nameC));
    }
    Path path = Paths.get("out.txt");
    saveToXml(new Items(items), new FileOutputStream(path.toFile()));
}
}
```

And the output:

```
<items idA="idA 17" idB="idB 17" idC="idC 17">
    <nameA>locationA 17</nameA>
    <nameB>locationB 17</nameB>
    <nameC>locationC 17<!--Item [nameA = locationA 17, nameB = locationB 17, nameC = locationC 17]--><!--Item [nameA = locationA 18, nameB = locationB 18, nameC = locationC 18]--><!--Item [nameA = locationA 19, nameB = locationB 19, nameC = locationC 19]--><!--Item [nameA = locationA 20, nameB = locationB 20, nameC = locationC 20]--><!--Item [nameA = locationA 21, nameB = locationB 21, nameC = locationC 21]--><!--Item [nameA = locationA 22, nameB = locationB 22, nameC = locationC 22]--></nameC>
</items>
```

But the comment is inside of the element, combined, and only sometimes, any ideas how to have comments after every item, and of course after the element?

Comment: using `ContentHandler` you can control the `startElement` event and work on that.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it. This stuff should be easier though, it's not an overfly complex matter.